# Calling close of different indices

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I am trying to build indicator based on latest close of stocks in 3 different markets.

I call close for the stock and the exchange. however when i select a stock in exchange that i do not have data subscription to live data the other stocks readings for stock close and exchange close are fetching one day ago values and this runes my indicator.

Need help to code the DLY exchanges to be able to get latest data from exchanges we are subscribing to for data.

Also I am getting wrong lock back values of 90 and 300 close when change stock chart.

```
//@version=5
//V316 lates ... v314 for coding hiding rows 
     
indicator('Close of Different Stocks', shorttitle='[BAH] Close  V01', overlay=true)
 
// Input for symbols
s01 = input.symbol('TADAWUL:1080', title="S01", group = "Symbols", display = display.none)
s02 = input.symbol('EGX:EGAS', title="S16", group = "Symbols", display = display.none)
s03 = input.symbol('BATS:LCID', title="S017", group = "Symbols", display = display.none)

c01 = request.security(s01,timeframe.period, close)
c01d = c01[90]
c01y = c01[300]

c02 = request.security(s02,timeframe.period, close)
c02d = c02[90]
c02y = c02[300]

c03 = request.security(s03,timeframe.period, close)
c03d = c03[90]
c03y = c03[300]

//publish dat of src, src90 and src300 in table
var tbl = table.new(position.top_right, 20, 40, frame_color=#26A69A, frame_width=1, border_width=2, border_color=color.new(color.white, 100))

// Table Headers
table.cell(tbl, 0, 0, "Index", bgcolor=color.new(color.gray, 90), text_size = size.small)
table.cell(tbl, 1, 0, "close", bgcolor=color.new(color.gray, 90), text_size = size.small)
table.cell(tbl, 2, 0, "closed", bgcolor=color.new(color.gray, 90), text_size = size.small)
table.cell(tbl, 3, 0, "closey", bgcolor=color.new(color.gray, 90), text_size = size.small)

table.cell(tbl, 1, 1, str.tostring(c01, format="#.##############"), text_size=size.small)
table.cell(tbl, 2, 1, str.tostring(c01d, format="#.##############"), text_size=size.small)
table.cell(tbl, 3, 1, str.tostring(c01y, format="#.##############"), text_size=size.small)

table.cell(tbl, 1, 2, str.tostring(c02, format="#.##############"), text_size=size.small)
table.cell(tbl, 2, 2, str.tostring(c02d, format="#.##############"), text_size=size.small)
table.cell(tbl, 3, 2, str.tostring(c02y, format="#.##############"), text_size=size.small)

table.cell(tbl, 1, 3, str.tostring(c03, format="#.##############"), text_size=size.small)
table.cell(tbl, 2, 3, str.tostring(c03d, format="#.##############"), text_size=size.small)
table.cell(tbl, 3, 3, str.tostring(c03y, format="#.##############"), text_size=size.small)
```